# Laravel hasMany returns an empty array or error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have seen a plethora of related questions but can't seem to figure out what is going on.
I am using Laravel 7.x, I have a Categories and a Products table.

Categories:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Products:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
    category_id int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    KEY category_id (category_id),
    CONSTRAINT products_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

In Laravel I can do `Product::first()->catgory` and then get the relevant category, with the `hasMany` relationship things seem to go pear shaped.

Defining Category as such:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

Gives the error:
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from categories where categories.category_id = 1 and categories.category_id is not null)`

Adding the foreign key and local key simply returns an empty array:

```
Category::find(1)->products;

...

public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id', 'category_id');
}

...

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#306 ▼
   #items: []
}
```

What is it that I am missing here?

***EDIT:**
Adding the FK as mentioned still results in the above mentioned SQL error

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
    }
}
```

alt tried...

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply having `return $this->hasMany(Product::class);` in your Category Model gave you an error?

Comment: Add just the foreign key to both models.. Product and Category
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id'); and....... return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');

Comment: @Digvijay yes, it gives the sql error above

Comment: @nikistag only using FK leads to same SQL error: `return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');`

Comment: I started from scratch and everything is working now - Must either have been a typo, or a DB error. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

your problem lies in this relation:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id', 'category_id');
}
```

hasMany take as a second parameter the foreign key of the relation in the many table ...
the third parameter represent the local primary key ... in this case the Category local primary key .. by default should be 'id'
when you write category_id as the third parameter laravel look for the 
column category_id in category and it did not find it ...

in Category model the relation should be:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
}
```

the opposite relation in Product class should be:

```
 public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

more details

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: i have also tried that, see my edit.

Comment: you tried:  return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'id', 'category_id');
not return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');

Comment: `public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id');
    }` and `public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }` still gives sql error

Comment: using your updated answer with `Category::find(1)->products;` still gives the SQL error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'categories.category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`category_id` = 1 and `categories`.`category_id` is not null)`

Comment: please make sure you  set      protected $table = 'products'; 
protected $fillable = [your fillable column] , in Product Model and the same for Category model

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id','id');
    }
```